# Android post request using Httppost without urlencode parameter

Tags: java, android, http-post

That's my code... is it possible to remove the urlencode?
I want to pass post parameters without urlencode them.
Thanks

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "Hi"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
BasicHttpEntity filter = new BasicHttpEntity();
filter.setContent(new ByteArrayInputStream("Filter=id :EQUALS: 12345 :AND: stringdata :EQUALS: hi".getBytes("UTF-8")));
httppost.setEntity(filter);
```

Thanks